# Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext when running SB project as Jar file, but fine when execute in IDEA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

My SpringBoot web-app builds fine, but when I try to execute the jar file it gives the unable to start error. When I run a Gradle bootRun in IDEA the web-app starts correctly and is fully functional.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start `ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.`

17:33:15.971 [main] WARN org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

SpringBoot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class ProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
}
```

}
Also I am using Jasypt to encrypt application properties.

App.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-

strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
server.port=8080
app.key = ENC(u+S5jaQft+NC5tHhtnZyNOl1bRskpmRufwK3aPuQYb0=)

# MariaDB / MySQL connection detail
jasypt.encryptor.password=Leaf23

spring.profiles.active=prod
server.error.path=/error
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

application-prod.properties:

```
# MariaDB / MySQL connection details
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/leafProject
spring.datasource.username=webappuser
spring.datasource.password=ENC(VJPGTDVqPqsBnnzKXOtj10sZ3/ui+Y38

# SSL information for TSL certification
server.ssl.key-store-password=ENC(c00xghLq85mdkdKKzrPUMy9h6fc02kfq)
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/leafyproject.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.error.path=/error
```

//build.gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'tree.leaf'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:3.0.3'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    runtime 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtime 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.0'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


tasks.bootRun.configure {
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev")
}

tasks.register("bootRunProd") {
    group = "application"
    description = "Runs the Spring Boot application with the prod profile"
    doFirst {
        tasks.bootRun.configure {
            systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "prod")
        }
    }
    finalizedBy("bootRun")
}
```

I don't know what to do as I need to be able to execute the .jar file. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How does your `application.properties` and gradle dependencies file look like?

Comment: @Renis1235 I have added them to the question, I think it may be because I am just using: gradlew build -> java -jar {jar}  when I need to be saying to do it using production application properties

Comment: try renaming your `application-production.properties` to `application-prod.properties`

Comment: @Renis1235 Sorry it already is I typed it wrong, fixed.

Comment: It looks like Tomcat is missing from the classpath but it should be there judging by the dependencies.. Can you please update your question with a listing of the jar’s contents and the output of running `java -jar {jar} --debug`?